# Self-Assignment in Delphi

Tags: delphi, vcl

In C++ there's a common idiom in assignment operators where you must avoid problems caused by copying an object to itself.

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/self-assignment-why.html

But, in Delphi VCL (at least in D2010) this doesn't seem to be handled well.

As an example, the following function will *clear* the `TStringList` passed to it!

```
procedure foo(var strings:TStringList)
begin 
  strings.Assign(strings);
end;
```

Is this still an issue with later versions of Delphi - or is there a common way of handling the problem?

Comment: What good would this code do, assuming it didn't have the problem you allege?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError : It's just intended to show the problem. Assigning to self can happen in unexpected places, and should just act as a NOOP.

Comment: The result is the same in XE6 as in D2010.

Comment: It is a fairly trivial change, of course, which must mean that it hasn't come up very often on the VCL team's radar.

Comment: @Roddy Is this behavior not by design ? According to the source code, TStrings.Assign will call clear at the very beginning.

Comment: @XichenLi It is by design.  Roddy's point is that the design convention is different from C++ and is further suggesting that, because the RTL implementation will result in clearing during self-assignment, that this is a design error.

Comment: @XichenLi - the 'designed behaviour' is that the destination is cleared before the source is written to it. But when source == destination, that clears the source too! So nothing gets copied.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Self assignment is rare in Delphi, which is why it is not commonly checked for.  Since class instances must be allocated on the heap, and the assignment operator is not overridable in classes, assignment from one object to another must be done explicitly, such as via `TPersistent.Assign()`.  The majority of Delphi users understand that and do not write code that would assign an object to itself, accidentally or otherwise.

Self assignment is more common in C++, especially since it can actually be generated by the compiler itself in some cases.  And the assignment operator is overloadable.  So it makes more sense to do self assignment checks in C++.

Comment: +1. This is the right answer: Delphi does not have C++'s problems, so it doesn't need C++ idioms as solutions to them.

Comment: +1, But I think it's even simpler: *assignment* is more common is C++. My C++Builder code copies objects by value all the time (e.g., in std::vectors), but there's many fewer cases where TObjects are assigned.

Comment: @Roddy If you need to copy, you need to copy. Doesn't matter what language. If you code in Delphi that works with the equivalent of `std::vector<T>`  then you'll want to copy just as much.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: True. Probably what I was trying to say (I think...) is that assignment of VCL objects is less common than of non-vcl objects. And in C++ you're likely to use things like std::vector<stringtype> (which are directly assignable) instead of TStrings objects, which require many more hoops.

Comment: If you use TStrings instead of `std::vector<string>` then you need to copy it in exactly the same circumstance that leads you to assign  the C++ vector. And then you are right back where we started. Remy's point is really that self assignment is more common in C++ and more importantly, much harder to avoid. Which makes it more important to protect on the inside.

Answer (score 4):

There's not much to say. You can deal with it in one of the following ways:

1. Add protection at the call site. Refrain from calling `Assign` when source and destination are the same.
2. Add protection in the implementation of `Assign`. Again you simply do nothing if source and destination are the same.

The design choice made throughout the RTL/VCL is the former. I'm not aware of any implementation of `Assign` in the RTL/VCL that checks for source and destination referring to the same object. Which means the onus is on you the caller to perform the checks.

Yes you could opt for option 2 in your own types. But now you'd be taking a design decision that clashes with that made in the RTL/VCL. Think long and hard before going down that route. Unless there are strong reasons to do otherwise you should always follow the precedent set by the framework.

I imagine that the designers of the RTL/VCL opted for option 1 because either they did not consider the issue, or they considered it and decided that it was too rare to justify adding checks to every implementation of `Assign`.

Answer (score 2):

The mistake is to assume that `Assign` is supposed to mean the same thing as the assignment operator in your familiar language. It is not.

[The documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.Classes.TPersistent.Assign) for `System.Classes.TPersistent.Assign` says the following:

> Copies the contents of another similar object.
>
> Call `Assign` to copy the properties or other attributes of one object from another.

It goes on to specifically say that `TPersistent.Assign` is not mean to be equivalent to the C++ assignment operator overload.

`TPersistent.Assign` is by design implementation specific and can have surprising results in some cases.

Comment: The same issues arise with `Assign` as do with with the C++ assignment operator.

Comment: "It goes on to specifically say" : You've misunderstood that. It says that (for both C++ and Delphi) `dest:=src` is different from `dest.assign(src)`. The former is basically just assigning pointers, rather than copying contents.

Comment: What I said was that the assignment operator overload is not the same as dest.assign(src). Assuming you haven't overloaded the assignment operator for the class, it is just copying the pointer. But if you read the example in the link in the OP, it is specifically overloading the assignment operator.

Comment: @AndersE.Andersen My question is *entirely* about Copying Objects By Value. In C++ this is conventionally done using the assignment operator. In Delphi VCL, this is done using `Assign`. This is not about using the assignment operator in Delphi, or copying pointers to objects in C++.

Comment: I completely understand. I can only refer to the documentation for `Assign`, which I think indicates that it works slightly differently than straight copy by value. I guess it could be a matter of interpretation. I think Remy's answer is very good. I kind of wish I wrote it. :)